# Installing PHP 5.3.3-24 on CentOS 6.5 (Final)

Tags: software-installation, yum, php, centos

I require a slightly older version of PHP for my server because I need to be able to exploit a CVE (CVE-2006-7243) that was patched in the newer versions. **NOTE:** This is a legitimate use case where we're setting up a web based penetration testing system for Computer Science students at my University.

PHP 5.3.3-24 would be perfect.

The current one that `yum` tries to install is 5.3.3-27.

I've tried sourcing old RPM's and found a lot here:
http://www.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/6/x86_64/RPMS/
but none of them being the version I would like.

How should I tackle installing this version of PHP?

Comment: Exploiting a security issue?  Geeze, I feel sorry for any of your customers or clients.

Comment: It is actually being used for a web based penetration testing system for Computer Science students at my University. I would ideally like to use CentOS 6.5 because I am comfortable with it and can be assured it can't be pwned in any way that I wasn't expecting. I would appreciate it if you could remove your -1

Comment: It might be worth explaining why you're after this version in your question - it did look a little suspect at first!  Is 5.3.3-23 close enough, which can be found via [RPM Bone](http://rpm.pbone.net), or does it have to be *.24?

Comment: If you look at the RPM changelog .23 should suffice. Remi Follet applied the patch to .25 for this exact CVE. See here: https://zid-lux1.uibk.ac.at/linux/rpm2html/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64.html. Scroll down to see the changelog for the php RPM.

Comment: I would either take .23 or take the .27 SRPM and remove the patch files that were added per the changelog, and rebuild .24 myself. I've looked in all my usual places and am not finding a pre-built option for you.

Comment: @garethTheRed -23 would be suitable however I cannot find it for CentOS6 on RPM Bone? Could only find it for 5.10?

Comment: [x86_64](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=26&dist=74&size=1179060&name=php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64.rpm) or [x32](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=26&dist=74&size=1167444&name=php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686.rpm). They are for RHEL6.4, but may work with yours.

Comment: @garethTheRed Thank you! That is super. The exploit works as expected. If you post it as an answer I would be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php-5.3.3-23`  is available on RPM Bone for RHEL6.4:

- [x86_64](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=26&dist=74&size=1179060&name=php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64.rpm)
- [x32](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=26&dist=74&size=1167444&name=php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686.rpm)

It's not the exact version you are after, but may fit the bill. If there are no dependency issues, then it should install.

Comment: Brilliant, this works fine with CentOS 6.5 FINAL. Thank you for your and the other commenters for their help.